# Qual è il significato di "nacchere" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La madre*, di Grazia Deledda, ho letto:

> La donna dal suo banco ascoltava quieta: le parole del prete cominciavano però a darle un certo malessere. Aprì il cassetto davanti a sé, dove teneva i denari e gli anelli con le corniole e le spille e le **nacchere** che le donne le consegnavano in pegno per dei piccoli prestiti: e pensieri maligni balenarono nei ripostigli più oscuri della sua mente come quei tristi gioielli in fondo al suo cassetto.

Dovete sapere che lo scenario di questo romanzo è un piccolo paesino della Sardegna del primo Novecento o di fine Ottocento.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa possono essere queste "nacchere" che appaiono in questo passaggio? Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che "nacchera" può essere un strumento musicale, un mollusco, oppure la parte interna della conchiglia di alcuni molluschi conosciuta anche come "madreperla". Tuttavia, dal contesto sembra che queste "nacchere" siano qualche sorta di gioielli.

Comment: Secondo me la tua intuizione è corretta, deve trattarsi di qualche tipo di bigiotteria; forse degli orecchini? (le nacchere come strumento musicale sono a coppie) o forse qualcosa in madreperla.

Comment: Cercando «nacchere di mare» in riferimento alla Sardegna si trovano vari articoli a un mollusco tipico di quelle coste (solo un esempio qui: http://www.ansa.it/sardegna/notizie/2018/12/10/nacchere-di-mare-a-rischio-estinzione_0b59fc93-aa33-46c7-acd2-95eadcc60aeb.html). È curioso che le nacchere di mare siano quelle del bisso, il preziosissimo filato conosciuto nel Mediterraneo in tempi antichi: la seta prima che ci fossero contatti con l’Oriente.

Comment: Ho dimenticato di aggiungere che ho cercato in riferimento alla Sardegna perché la Deledda è sarda e in Sardegna si svolge il romanzo.

Comment: @Benedetta: Non capisco bene: con qualche sostanza generata da questo mollusco si faceva la stoffa chiamata "bisso"?

Comment: @Charo Il bisso sono dei filamenti che poi venivano tessuti: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/bisso/